# How can I calculate properly the graph of a quadratic function?

Tags: graphing-functions

I want to know how to calculate this: (I don't know his name in english, or in spanish, our teacher call it "the little belly" :))
[image]
We've just today had the math final in school and we had to draw a function very similar like that one, our teacher say that we must write that part as we wish because it's too complicate to for us, she say that **maybe** at the end of the next year we would teach how to calculate this, but I don't have enought patience...

Actually I know this:
$$x^{2}+x-2$$

$\text{Domain} = \mathbb{R} \text{ or } (-\infty;+\infty)$
$\text{Roots (Intersection to x)} = (1;0) \text{ and }(-2;0)$
$$\frac{-1±\sqrt{1^{2}-4\times 1 \times (-2)}}{2\times 1}=0$$
$$\frac{-1±\sqrt{1+8}}{2}=0$$
$$\frac{-1±\sqrt{9}}{2}=0$$
$$\frac{-1±3}{2}=0$$
$$x_{1}=\frac{-1+3}{2}=\frac{2}{2}=1$$
$$x_{2}=\frac{-1-3}{2}=\frac{-4}{2}=-2$$
$\text{Sorted to Source (Intersection to y)} = (0;-2)$
$$0^{2}+0-2=0+0-2=-2$$
$\text{Vertex} = (-\frac{1}{2};-\frac{9}{4})$
$$x_{v}=\frac{-1}{2\times1}=\frac{-1}{2}=-\frac{1}{2}$$
$$y_{v}=(-\frac{1}{2})^{2}+(-\frac{1}{2})-2$$
$$y_{v}=(-\frac{1}{4})-\frac{1}{2}-2$$
$$y_{v}=(-\frac{1}{4})-\frac{1}{2}-2$$
$$y_{v}=-\frac{9}{4}$$

And finally (In spanish we use the letter $C$, but I am not sure if in english it would be $S$ (set instead of "conjunto")):

- $\text{Image} = (+\infty;-\frac{9}{4})$
- $C^{+} = (-\infty;-2) U (1;+\infty)$
- $C^{-} = (-2;1)$
- $C^{↑} = (-\frac{1}{2};+\infty)$
- $C^{↓} = (-\infty;-\frac{1}{2})$
- $C^{0} = \text{{-2;1}}$

But with all this values I only know:

- Where the function pass throught the y.
- Where the function pass throught the x (two times).
- And where the function stop decreasing and start increasing (also the bottom of it, where it's the "belly").

But with that information I can only make straight lines, not curves like in the picture. How can I know how to make them curves?

With my current information I can only do (in red):
[image]

My only idea is to use a table of values, but even with that it can't be very precise, or at least without an huge effort (using a table with **a lot** of values).

Comment: you just have to curve it in terms of sketching. This in't art class.

Comment: @user29418, just that? But, I would be really unprecise.

Comment: @AirConditioner, I know where is the bottom part of the "belly"... (That is called vertex?), but I want to know how to make a more precise draw from the root to the bottom, and from the bottom to the another root.

Comment: I recommend learning how to graph by hand; you can get a pdf  https://www.printablepaper.net/category/graph  and print out graph paper as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rounding our evaluation to the nearest half grid resolution ($0.25$), we trivially realize that:

- The center of the parabola is $(x_0,y_0)=(-0.5,-2.25)$,
- The parabola passes through $(2,4)$
- The parabola passes through $(-3,4)$, hence it is a y-axis parabola.

From the equation of the parabola:
$$
y-y_0=\frac{1}{4p}(x-x_0)^2
$$
we evaluate and find the focus:
$$
4+2.25=\frac{1}{4p}(2+0.5)^{2}\\
6.25 * 4p=1*(2+0.5)^{2}\\
25p = 6.25\\
p = \frac{6.25}{25}= \frac{1}{4}
$$
Hence the equation is:
$$
y=(x+0.5)^2-2.25
$$

From here you are ready. You can simply have a table for each parabola point in the given grid. Note the symmetry on the y values, confirming the parabola has the vertical line as axis:
$$
\begin{array}{c}
x& y\\
-3& 4\\
-2.5& 1.75\\
-2& 0\\
-1.5& -1.25\\
-1& -2\\
-0.5& -2.25\\
0& -2\\
0.5& -1.25\\
1& 0\\
1.5& 1.75\\
2& 4
\end{array}
$$

Or draw it in any mathematical package like [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3D(x%2B0.5)%5E2-2.25).

If you indeed want to draw it by hand, the parabola focus is:
$(x_0,y_0+p)=(-0.5,-2)$ and the directrix is $y=y_0-p=-2.5$, and then the artwork follows as shown [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eZJrIYt7gBo).

Comment: Sorry but I am not understanding somethings that you said: 1) I don't understand what are you trying to say in the first line of your answer. 2) The center of the parabola is (−0.5,−2.25), but why you use (2,4) and (−3,4) and not other values where the parabola passes? 3) I don't undestand why are you making that equation in order to make the table where you can simply use the function itself $x^{2}+x−2$ (it provides the same results). 4) And finally, I saw the videou but I don't understand how you get $p$. I am sorry for my doubts, this is new for me.

Comment: Lets explain. 1) I assumed you only had the chart and nothing more, hence your best guess is to figure the closest values. 2) I chose the more distanced points just to be sure about the growth ratio of the parabola. 3) Having the equation make the equation finding pointsless actually. 4) $p$ is the value in the equation given in my answer, and it is the focal distance. This serves for giving you the focal point and the directrix, if you intend to draw them, or if you intend to draw the parabola using a ruler pencil and paper.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! I now understand it much better. But I still haven't understanded about $p$, I don't know how you get $p$, what calculation did you do in order to get $p = \frac{1}{4}$?

Comment: I just replaced one of the points and the center :)

Comment: Ahh, now I understand, you simply resolve the equation! Thanks you.